# Limit of a sequence: $\left(\cos\left(\frac1n\right)\right)^n$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How can I solve 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\cos\left(\frac1n\right)\right)^n$$
without using calculus?

Comment: Limit as $n$ tends to what?

Comment: n tends to Infinity

Comment: Limits are calculus, how can you solve a calculus question without calculus?

Comment: Sorry I meant things like taylor series etc

Comment: What are we allowed to use ?

Comment: As basic as possible.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming $\lim_{u\to \infty} (1-1/u)^u = 1/e,$ we can argue this way: $\cos^2(1/n) + \sin^2(1/n) = 1$ and $\sin (1/n) < 1/n.$ This gives $\cos^2(1/n)>  1-1/n^2.$ Therefore

$$(1-1/n^2)^{n/2} < [\cos (1/n)]^n < 1.$$

The term on the left equals $[(1-1/n^2)^{n^2}]^{1/(2n)}.$ As $n\to \infty,$ the limit inside the brackets is $1/e.$ Raising to the $1/(2n)$ power then gives a limit of $(1/e)^0 = 1.$ Thus the desired limit is $1$ by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: +1 I like the way you conclude that $\cos^2(1/n) > 1-1/n^2$.  Neat!

Answer (score 3):

Something generally like the following?

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right]^n
    & = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[1-\frac{1}{2n^2}+o(n^{-3})\right]^n \\
    & = \lim_{n \to \infty} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2n}+o(n^{-2})\right] \\
    & = 1
\end{align}

Comment: I always get little-o notation screwed up, so I'd appreciate it if someone pointed such out if I did (and of course any other errors).

Answer (score 2):

We must use some standard limits. We have:
$$ \begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} (\cos(1/n))^n &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\exp\left( \dfrac{\cos(1/n) - 1}{1/n} \right) \\
&= \exp(0) = 1
\end{align}$$

---

<sup>My original answer asserted this: "Using the basic concepts of limits, we imagine inserting a very large value of $n$, say $10^6$. The cosine will spit out a value very close to $1$, but **less than one**. This value is raised to a very large power, so the value diminishes and tends to zero." This was proved wrong by my own formal calculation and WoframAlpha. I would appreciate some insight into why this loose method didn't work!</sup>

Comment: I don't see this.  The fraction in your second-to-last step tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, not $-\infty$.

Comment: @BrianTung Just as I posted the answer, it struck me that my answer is wrong. My bad. Could you provide some insight on this?

Comment: Some insight comes from the Taylor series expansion: The first two (and most important) terms are $\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \cdots$.  With $x = \frac{1}{n}$, we get $\cos = 1 - \frac{1}{2n^2} + \cdots$.  If you raise that to the $n$th power, you only get $\exp(-1/2n)$.

Comment: @FreezingFire i did not get how you got $$(\cos(1/n))^n = \exp\left( \dfrac{\cos(1/n) - 1}{1/n} \right)$$. Can you please explain it to me. Thanks.

Comment: @FreezingFire The value is very close to one, and less than one, but it is not constant. If it was constant, the limit would have been zero. However, the value gets arbitrarily close to one as $n$ increases, and it turns out that the net effect results in the limit being equal to one.

Answer (score 1):

$$y = \cos^n (1/n)$$
$$y = \exp\left({\log(\cos (1/n))\over 1/n}\right)$$

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} y = \lim_{n \to \infty} \exp\left({\log(\cos (1/n))\over 1/n}\right)= \lim_{x \to 0} \exp\left({\log(\cos (x))\over x}\right)-(1)$$

$$ =  \exp\left( {[\log(\cos (x))]'\over [x]'}\large{|}_{x=0}\right)-(2)$$

$$=  \exp\left( {-\tan 0 \over 1}\right) = \exp\left(0\right) = 1$$

> $(1)-$ substituing ${1\over n} = x$
>
> $(2)-$ L'Hospital's Rule